# Alertmanager Send Resolved to a separate channel

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

We have configured Prometheus-based alerts for our system and it works fine. The alerts are going to specific channels in Slack and Teams. For the purpose generating tickets and auto-closure of tickets (on resolved messages) we are sending Resolved status for one single alert. Now, the support guys are looking into alerts in the main slack channel and they don't want to receive the resolved notification there (which is mainly for auto closure of ticket). Is there any way we can send the Resolved notifications to another channel instead of the channel where it posts the alerts?

This is an excerpt from the config

```
    - match_re:
        component: 'platform'
      receiver: 'slack-notifications-platform'
      continue: false

- name: 'slack-notifications-platform'
  slack_configs:
  - send_resolved: true
    api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T091V/B8UHDTR/hfY66GDhwvRD5myKbZ88cva'
    channel: '#telemetry_alerts_ops'
    color: '{{ if eq .Status "resolved" }}good{{ else }}{{ if eq .CommonLabels.severity "minor"}}warning{{ else }}danger{{ end }}{{ end }}'
    title: '{{ if gt (.Alerts.Firing | len) 0 }}[FIRING: {{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}]{{ end }}{{ if gt (.Alerts.Resolved | len) 0 }}[RESOLVED: {{ .Alerts.Resolved | len }}]{{ end }}{{ .GroupLabels.alertname }} ({{ .CommonLabels.severity }})'
    text: '{{ template "slack.common.text" . }}'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could sort of hack it by sending it to both channels and only setting send_resolved to true in one of them.

Both channels will still receive the alert that way but only one will receive the resolve.

You'd need to use the `continue` option on the route so that it sends the alert to both routes.

Docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route